# KeyListener para vários JTextFields

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, listener

Criei um `KeyListener` para verificação de uma `String` digitada, se esta encontra-se no banco. Se sim deixa prosseguir, se não, emite um alerta.

A dúvida agora é que tenho cerca de 50 `jTextFields`. É possível criar um `KeyListener` que possa ser usado para todos os `jTextFields`? Ou tenho que criar um para cada `jTextField`? Pois no meu código eu especifico que estou pegando a `String` do `jTextField1` por exemplo, não servindo para o que preciso agora.

Aqui está o código do `KeyListener`

```
private final KeyListener listener = new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            int max = 4;
            if (max == 4) {
                String digitado = jTextField1.getText().trim();
                if (digitado.length() == max) {
                    verificaStringDigitada(digitado);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    };
```

Método que faz a verificação

```
public void verificaStringDigitada(String teste) {
        CarroDao carroDao = new CarroDao();
        List<Carro> carros = new ArrayList();
        carros = carroDao.consultarCarros();
        boolean ver = false;
        for (Carro carro : carros) {
            if (carros.contains(teste)) {
                ver = true;
            }
        }
        if (ver == false) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Verifique a digitação!");
            jTextField1.setText("");
        }
    }
```

Update1:

```
private final KeyAdapter listener = new KeyAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            JTextField field = (JTextField) e.getSource();

            int max = 4;
            if (max == 4) {
                String digitado = field.getText().trim();
                if (digitado.length() == max) {
                    CarroDao carroDao = new CarroDao();
                    List<Carro> carros = new ArrayList();
                    carros = carroDao.consultarCarros();
                    boolean ver = false;
                    for (Carro carro : carros) {
                        if (digitado.equals(carro.getNumero())) {
                            ver = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (ver == false) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Verifique a digitação!");
                        field.setText("");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode generalizar desta forma:

```
private final KeyAdapter listener = new KeyAdapter() {

  @Override
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    JTextField field = (JTextField) e.getSource();

      int max = 4;
      if (max == 4) {
          String digitado = field.getText().trim();
          if (digitado.length() == max) {
              CarroDao carroDao = new CarroDao();
              List<Carro> carros = new ArrayList();
              carros = carroDao.consultarCarros();
              boolean ver = false;
              for (Carro carro : carros) {
                  if (carros.contains(digitado)) {
                      ver = true;
                 }
              }
              if (!ver) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Verifique a digitação!");
                  field.setText("");
              }
          }
      }
  }
};
```

Ou transformando em uma classe a parte:

```
class MeuKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

  @Override
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    JTextField field = (JTextField) e.getSource();

      int max = 4;
      if (max == 4) {
          String digitado = field.getText().trim();
          if (digitado.length() == max) {
              CarroDao carroDao = new CarroDao();
              List<Carro> carros = new ArrayList();
              carros = carroDao.consultarCarros();
              boolean ver = false;
              for (Carro carro : carros) {
                  if (carros.contains(digitado)) {
                      ver = true;
                 }
              }
              if (!ver) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Verifique a digitação!");
                  field.setText("");
              }
          }
      }
  }  
}
```

O segredo para tornar o keylistener genérico é obter um objeto do tipo `JTextField` a partir do próprio evento, como é feito na linha `JTextField field = (JTextField) e.getSource();`. Desta forma, não importará para o listener se você vai aplicar a um ou a 100 campos de textos diferentes.

Unifiquei o método pois entendi que se o objetivo dele é checar algo digitado nos campos de textos, ele pode ser parte do listener também.

Comment: usei sua primeira sugestão, porém esta entrando no `ver == false`, mesmo que o valor digitado esteja no banco. Não consegui descobrir o porque ainda .

Comment: Consegui algo, acrescentei o código em "update1" na questão.A princípio agora está verificando corretamente, quando o valor não está na lista, exibe o `JOptionPane` , quando está , prossegue.  Gostaria ainda de descobrir o porque de não estar funcionando da fora sugerida anterior.

Comment: @Rodrigo forneça um **[mcve]** da sua aplicação então, não tem como sugerir mais nada alem disso pois não há nada para testar.

Comment: @Rodrigo veja a edição, se ainda persistir, faça o que orientei no comentário anterior.